# How to make ivy leaves point in different directions?

Tags: texturing

I have ivy generated on an object. I would like to know the best way to have the leaves pointing in different directions instead of all of them pointing the same way.
[image]

Comment: It depends on the method you used to create the leaves, did you use particles or Geometry nodes or any other method? The screenshot doesn't show much but the material of the object you put the ivy on.

Comment: I didn't do anything to create the leaves. Blender adds them with the vines it creates with ivy generator.

Comment: I don't know any option to change the leaves orientation for the default ivy leaves, maybe you need to uncheck `Grow leaves` and manually add leaves with hair particles?